# Create a overlay when hovering over text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have a simple file based with html that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Faculty</b><br><br>
        Dr Mcgee
        <br>
        Dr Else
        <br><br>
        <b>Values</b><br><br>
        1
        <br>
        2
        <br>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm new to the web end of things, and was wondering how I could go about doing this: When the user hovers over a piece of text that's under the Faculty column of my school (I'm not gonna link my schools page because if I do someone from my school will likely create this extension). I want it to show a ratemyproff rating.

I have no idea on how to do this, because well I don't really know what to search on google to do such a thing?

I know there are CSS overlays over images like such:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

But in my case, I'm not guaranteed what professors will be listed (I just want to understand the basic process of doing such things).

I don't think I can use PHP as that would require users who I want to share this eventually with to also have a php/server side thing installed. I guess I just don't know how to go about doing such a thing, and don't know what to search on the internet for it?

Comment: You might struggle without a back-end to retrieve the data as any AJAX requests from the browser will normally be limited to same-origin

Comment: Also, unless the site has an API it might be against their Terms & Conditions to scrape the site.

Comment: @phuzi I think you're getting ahead of yourself, this is a much simpler request from what I understand, but how can you get any requests or do anything at all if the Schools in the html are not even in a tag

Comment: It's more so to do with my schools (University's) course selection system, I essentially want to make chrome extension  that once one hovers over a proffs name, it shows their rating. I didn't want to include this because someone from my school will likely read this and make such an extension (for my school), before I do.

Comment: I've updated my question in regards to what I actually want to do. Note that my schools page obviously isn't a simple html file, I'm just using that as an example as a novice programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sites you are requesting data from aren't under your control you are very likely not going to be able to do this without a backend because of CORS, which basically prohibits site A from loading in data from site B. Site B would have to give you special permission. You can read about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

However, if you are able to access the pages, or you decide to use a backend for this, the term you are looking for is ajax.

A rough outline of what your script might look like is:

- Give these school elements a classname.
- Also add [data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) to these elements to store data needed to get the information you are looking for (e.g. a url or a school name or id).
- In the JS, set up a trigger so that when something with that classname is hovered over, an ajax request is made to a url to get the data you are looking for.
- If the ajax request is successful, show the data you want to show in a container set up on the page.
- As far as setting up the container to show, it would probably be simplest to add an empty container for each listing which will then be populated with data.

If you are new to all of this, I would suggest using jQuery. You can find the ajax documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: What do you mean by not under my control? The sites are used for students to select courses, but anybody can search courses on those specific sites. So I'm not sure? A lot of these terms are new to me.

Comment: Browsers will only let you make ajax requests to resources on your same domain, for security reasons. So if your schools site is www.learning.edu but you are hosting at www.somestudent.com and try to make an ajax request from somestudent.com to learning.edu, you will see an error in the console ad the data will not load. However, if you are able to, or get someone at learning.edu to implement CORS headers, then exceptions can be made for requests from certain domains (or opened to everyone). I hope that helps clarify what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

First Step:

Use something to get the text and store in a javascript variable when hovered over the text that is searchable, 
To do this put the text in a single node like `<span class="searchable">This text is searchable</span>.`

You can do something like this to get node value http://jsfiddle.net/5gyRx/

Second step:

Add an empty node `<div class="data"></div>` aboslutely positioned inside the container div which will be used to show fetched details about that text.

Third step:

Use JavaScript/jQuery to fire an Ajax call with the text you got from the first step and populate the empty node created earlier with this data.

Comment: I've updated my question to more of what I want, but I think your answer is still relevant?